# Algebra of Linear algebra [Intermediate level]

Tags: linear-algebra

Good day people,

I was wondering how to solve some linear algebra problems (3 in total).

At first sight it looks easy. But **between lines**. *It isn't*.

**First problem**: Find the matrix: $$X$$  iff it exists in the following operation:

$$XA=BX$$

$$X\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  4&7 \\ 
  { - 5}&3 
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  3&1&{ - 2} \\ 
  { - 1}&2&2 \\ 
  5&0&{ - 2} 
\end{array}} \right)X$$

**Second problem**: Giving the definition of this new operation, denoted by '*' : $$A * B = BA + (BA)^{T}$$

Then, $$ B^{-1} * A$$ is equal to?

**Third problem**: Giving the following definitions of new operations, denoted by '*' and 'o':

1. $$A * B = 1/2 (AB^{T} + B^{T}A)$$
2. $$A \circ B = 1/2 (AB^{T} + BA^{T})$$

where **A** and **B** are symmetric and invertible. Then, $$(A * B) \circ B^{-1}$$ is equal to?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: @Alejandro: I tried to edit (waiting for approval) but I don't understand the grey part. What is (4,7) ? (3,1,-2)? etc...

Comment: @SergioParreiras Please, I don't know how to write down a matrix in this enviroment, can you help me out? thanks in advance... relate to the another symbol ... * , it not means \times, the simple multiplication operation... as I staed before... is a NEW OPERATION. Thanks

Comment: For matrix equations it is useful to use kronecker product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations

Comment: Thanks @tom , can you explain me how to solve these operations? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first question let $X$ be $m\times n$ matrices.

Since you can write $XA$ where $A$ is $2\times 2$ matrices we must have $n=2$ and we can write $BX$ where $B$ is $3\times 3$ matrices then $m=3$.

Thus, $X$ is $3\times 2$ matrices. $X=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  a&b \\ 
   c&d \\ e & f
\end{array}} \right)$

From that point it is easy to find $a,b,c,d $ and  $e$ by using the given equation. (just use matrix multiplication).